# mediaelement.js not playing wav files in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, wav, mediaelement.js

I've started trying to use mediaelement.js as a cross browser / OS audio player.

At the moment, I'm trying to get it to play WAV files.

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox (now I've made sure the URL for the src is all lower case!) but in IE8 it doesn't work.  I'm getting slightly different behaviour depending on whether I'm running from the IIS server on my Windows 7 machine (which shows the player but doesn't do anything), or on a Windows 2003 IIS server (which just shows a black box without any player controls)

I can see from the IIS log that the silverlightmediaelement.axp file is getting to the browser.

If I look at the page in the IE Developer Tools page, I can see the silverlight object is there.

Can anyone suggest how to get this working, or any ways to debug this further?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added an HTML5 shim to the top of your `head`? I was racking my brain trying to figure out why IE wasn't playing the `audio` element (with multiple `source`s), until I looked at the DOM tree and saw the notorious issue whereby IE fails to parse HTML5 elements. Once I added the [HTML5 Enabling Script](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/), it worked beautifully.